# Newtonsoft.json nuget package, not found C#, .net framework

Tags: c#, build, reference, json.net

I am working on a remote application via FTP.

I have installed the nuget package Newtonsoft.json.

If I create a page in the directory root, I can access the library fine with:

```
Using Newtonsoft.Json
```

But if I create a page inside any sub-directory, and try to reference

```
Using Newtonsoft.Json
```

I get a compilation error :
The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Why does the package only work on pages in the root directory, and not on pages in sub-directories?

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing the package multiple times at various versions, mostly the latest version.

I have checked the build and target compilation .net versions.

There is no reference to newtonsoft in my webconfig anywhere. This is a brand new empty application just created.

Comment: what *kind* of application is this - and using what framework (version) are you targeting? you mention webconfig - is this legacy asp.net mvc? or...?

Comment: Its a blank empty website. its legacy framework. 4.8.1 . It seems for some reason, its not knowing that the package is installed on pages in sub-directories, but works on any page in the root directory fine.

Comment: can you provide a screen shot of the solution view with all directories expanded and the code referenced as "page" where newtonsoft is not found please. Will help identify if its mvc or aspx

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to the hosting support and they informed me I would need to create the subfolder as an ASP.NET application on its own.

After doing this, I added the bin folder of dlls to that sub directory, and all subsequent pages inside it found manage to reference them fine.

It seems the problem was related to working on the root directory under the hosting providers specific hosting setup.

All sorted now :)